# Is there a way to directly message a user?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I wanted to send @kiamlaluno a note to say congratulations on being the first user to earn a gold badge. (Voting on 600 questions? That must have taken a lot of time!). But I don't see any way to send a direct message, and I don't think meta is an appropriate place for that sort of completely OT community cheerleading. Am I missing anything? Or maybe we could have a single topic on meta just for community chitchat, using @ tags so people see it?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported, and there are no plans to that I am aware of. (There are one or more MSO requests for this).

Additionally, the `@` modifier *only* works in comments. Maintaining a topic on meta would not really be feasible, since a user must have participated in the actual commented item in some manner. It is also not an appropriate usage of meta.

You could just leave a comment on one of his many questions. Alternatively, there is [the third place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/chat-now-in-public-beta/) which is intended for chat.

Comment: Ah, the third place looks like the perfect solution, at least once it rolled out to our site.

Comment: @Michael: You can still use it now, but it's really hit or miss as to who is online at any time. I've tried creating a "cooking" room, but the traffic was dismally slow (non-existent). The highest trafficked rooms are the moderator chat, and "the tavern" (general chat).

Comment: Yeah, I think it will work better once we have the chat.cooking.stackexchange url.